# How to fix ios floating point error?

Tags: ios, floating-point, cgrect

```
let rectA = container.bounds.insetBy(20.0) // should be (20.0, 20.0, 335.0, 563.0) 
let rectB = child.frame // should be (20.0, 366.0, 217.0, 217.0)
let contain = rectA.contains(rectB) // give false
let union = rectA.union(rectB) // give (20.0, 20.0, 335.0, 563.0)
let xEq = rectA.x == union.x // give false
let yEq = rectA.y == union.y // give true
let widthEq = rectA.width == union.width // give true
let heightEq = rectA.height == union.height // give true
```

According to apple docs : `contains:` return true if the rectangle specified by rect2 is contained in the rectangle passed in rect1; otherwise, false. The first rectangle contains the second if the union of the two rectangles is equal to the first rectangle.

I think there the error is caused by floating point error. Anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't get floating point errors if all the decimal place values are 0.  That said, if your comments are correct I don't see why this is happening. You say what the values "should be" - have you verified these "are" the values?

Comment: Since I am dragging the child view around, I think the value of child.frame is not exactly equals to (20.0, 366.0, 217.0, 217.0).

Comment: If you're using `UIView`, you can easy debug with xcode
https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/special_debugging_workflows.html